# How do I convert my txt file to a String

Tags: java, string, file

How to I convert my txt file to a `String` that I read in my `newGame` method? I need to use my given interface.  The txt file used is a 9x9 matrix.  Then I need to convert that into a 2D array, how may I go about converting the String file in to a 2D int file as well.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;


public class GameManager implements SudokuBoardManager
{

private static GameManager myBoard;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    myBoard = new GameManager();
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    myBoard.newGame(chooser.getSelectedFile());
    System.out.println(myBoard.toString());


}

@Override
public void setValueAt(int r, int c, int v) throws InputOutOfRangeException, ValueNotValidException 
{


}

@Override
public int getValueAt(int r, int c) throws InputOutOfRangeException 
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int[] displayPossibleValues(int r, int c)throws InputOutOfRangeException 
{
    return null;
}

public String toString()
{

    return " ";
}

@Override
public void newGame(File gameFile) 
{
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    int status;
    Scanner in = null;

    chooser.setDialogTitle("Select Sudoku Game File");
    status = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        try
        {
            gameFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            in = new Scanner(gameFile); 
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}




}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try -

```
String output = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

Comment: This will dump all the file content in String in one go.. no need to call it in loop

Answer (score 1):

You could match with your data with the interface using a comma/newline delimited `Scanner` with nested for loop:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("game.txt")).useDelimiter(",|\r\n");
for (int i=0; i < 9; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j < 9; j++) {
      myBoard.setValueAt(i, j, scanner.nextInt());
   }
}
```

Setter would look like this:

```
public void setValueAt(int r, int c, int v) throws InputOutOfRangeException, ValueNotValidException {
    // Handle InputOutOfRangeException, ValueNotValidException
    boardValues[r][c] = v;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how I may use match and passed class in a loop to create a 2D array in the setValueAt method?

Comment: So this will create a 2D array, how do I call the entire array in my main when I need to output it

Answer (score 0):

Just read each line using BufferedReaders readline() method. Then find the integers in that line one by one & keep adding them in your 2d array.

Comment: I'm supposed to also Return string representation of the sudoku board in the following format:
  *   0,0,2,0,8,0,0,0,1 (new line)
  *   1,0,0,4,0,2,0,0,6 (new line)
for the toString() method, should I do that in toString()? or in newGame and just return the value in toString():

Comment: toString() methods are used for String representation of objects. So, if that's not the case, you should place your code in different method.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.readFully()` and `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.readLines`.

The url is http://commons.apache.org/io/